Getting the token as undefined since I get the token from backend (Angular, .NET)
I got a JWT authentication system with gRPC service in .NET and anular as client side,
everything seems alright except I can't store my token in the localStorage in client side, I got the token from backend but whenever I try to set it into the localStorage I got the token as undefined
this is my gRPC service backend :
using Grpc.Core;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

public class AuthServiceImpl : AuthService.AuthServiceBase {
    private readonly ITokenService _tokenService;
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;

    private readonly ILogger<AuthServiceImpl> _logger;
    
    public AuthServiceImpl(ITokenService tokenService, UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, ILogger<AuthServiceImpl> logger) {
        _tokenService = tokenService;
        _userManager = userManager;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public override async Task<AuthResponse> Login(LoginRequest request, ServerCallContext context) {
        var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(request.Username);

        if (user == null) {
        
        return new AuthResponse
            {
                Token = "",
                Success = false,
                Message = "Invalid username or password."
            };
        }
        var passwordHasher = new PasswordHasher<ApplicationUser>();
        var result = passwordHasher.VerifyHashedPassword(user, user.PasswordHash, request.Password);

        if (result == PasswordVerificationResult.Failed) {
            return new AuthResponse {
                Token = "",
                Success = false,
                Message = "Invalid username or password."
            };
        }
        _logger.LogInformation("Received gRPC request: {Request}", request);
        var token = _tokenService.GenerateToken(user.UserName, user.Email);
        _logger.LogInformation(token);
        return new AuthResponse {
            Token = token, Success = true, Message = "Done!"
        };
        // return await Task.FromResult(new AuthResponse { Token = token, Success=true, Message="Done!" });

    }


    public override async Task<AuthResponse> SignUp(SignUpRequest request, ServerCallContext context) {
        Console.WriteLine($"Received sign-up request: Username={request.Username}, Email={request.Email}");
        var user = new ApplicationUser
        {
            UserName = request.Username,
            Email = request.Email
        };
        var passwordHasher = new PasswordHasher<ApplicationUser>();
        user.PasswordHash = passwordHasher.HashPassword(user, request.Password);

        var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user);

        if (!result.Succeeded) {
            Console.WriteLine(result.Errors);
            var errors = string.Join(", ", result.Errors.Select(e => e.Description));
            return new AuthResponse {
                Token = "",
                Success = false,
                Message = $"User creation failed: {errors}"

            };
        }

        var token = _tokenService.GenerateToken(request.Username, request.Email);
        return await Task.FromResult(new AuthResponse {Token = token, Message = "added", Success = true});
    }
}

this is my token generator:
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;

public class TokenService : ITokenService {
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

    public TokenService(IConfiguration configuration) {
        _configuration = configuration;
    }

    public string GenerateToken( string username, string email) {
        var claims = new[] {
            new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, username),
            new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
    };


        var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_configuration["Jwt:Key"]));
        var creds = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);
        
        var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
            issuer: _configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
            audience: _configuration["Jwt:Audience"],
            claims: claims,
            expires: DateTime.Now.AddDays(10),
            signingCredentials: creds);
        
        return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
 
    }

}

and this is my login component:
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { AuthService } from '../../auth.service';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule],
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',

})


export class LoginComponent {
  loginForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private authService: AuthService) {
    this.loginForm = this.fb.group({
      username: ['', Validators.required],
      password: ['', Validators.required]
    });
  }

  onSubmit() {
    if (this.loginForm.valid) {
      this.authService.login(this.loginForm.value).subscribe((response : any) => {
        
        // both of these giving me undefined token
        const token1 =response[0];
        
        // undefined token
        const token = response.toen;
        console.log(token1);
        console.log(token);
        try{
          console.log(response);
          localStorage.setItem('token', token);
        } catch (e) {
          console.error(e);
        }
      });
    }
  }
}


this is my auth service in angular :
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthServiceClient } from './proto/auth_pb_service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { LoginRequest, SignUpRequest } from './proto/auth_pb';
import { BrowserHeaders } from 'browser-headers';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})


export class AuthService {
  private client: AuthServiceClient;

  constructor() {
    this.client = new AuthServiceClient('http://127.0.0.1:5002');
  }


  login(credentials: { username: string, password: string }): Observable<any> {
    const request = new LoginRequest();
    request.setUsername(credentials.username);
    request.setPassword(credentials.password);

    return new Observable(observer => {
      this.client.login(request, (error: any, response) => {
        if (error) {
          observer.error(error);
        } else {
          observer.next(response)
          observer.complete()
        }
        },)
      });
    };


  signUp(credentials: { Username: string, Password: string, Email: string}): Observable<any> {
    const request = new SignUpRequest();
    request.setUsername(credentials.Username);
    request.setEmail(credentials.Email);
    request.setPassword(credentials.Password);


    console.log('Sending sign up request with:', credentials);

    return new Observable(observer => {
      this.client.signUp(request, (error: any, response) => {
        if (error) {
          observer.error(error);
        } else {
          observer.next(response)
          console.log("this is the response", response)
          observer.complete()
        }
      })
    })
  }
}


and also this is the response that I got from backend
Object { f: null, b: undefined, D: -1, u: (3) […], G: 1.7976931348623157e+308, a: {} }
​
D: -1
​
G: 1.7976931348623157e+308
​
a: Object {  }
​
b: undefined
​
f: null
​
u: Array(3) [ "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJtYXRpbjEiLCJqdGkiOiJlYTFkZWFjZi03Njg4LTQ0NzAtYTcyNi0wNWY1OGNjZDE0NzQiLCJleHAiOjE3Mjc1OTIxMTgsImlzcyI6IjEyNy4wLjAuMTo1MDAyIiwiYXVkIjoiMTI3LjAuMC4xOjQyMDAifQ.2YENWX2v1h8LlUN4Joun-dSGIfwu1eNP6nIPeDzrVE4", "Done!", true ]

also I got a interceptor that assign headers to my requests :
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpEvent } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class HttpInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    if (req.url.includes('/song/add') && req.method === 'POST') {
      const clonedRequest = req.clone({
        headers: req.headers.delete('Content-Type')
      });
      return next.handle(clonedRequest);
    }
    const modifiedReq = req.clone({
      headers: req.headers
        .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
        .set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
    });
    return next.handle(modifiedReq);
  }
}


I have to mention this that everything seems alright, even I've tested my grpc service with bloomrpc and it was generating new tokens
ask me for more code if needed.

Assuming the response printed in the console with console.log(response); is this compound object and the token is returned in u then why sould you try to read it from response[0]? I'd try response.u[0].

@WiktorZychla Thank you sir, I'm just new in angular, I really appreciate your help.
